# Implementing 'saved books' cart in Django

Tags: python, django, cart

I'd like to implement a cart page, where i can save all the books that i've saved before

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ukr', 'Ukrainian'),
    ('eng', 'English'),
    ('rus', 'Russian'),
)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='4.jpg')
title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGES, default='English', max_length=100)
# many books has one genre, if genre is deleted then delete related books
genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=CASCADE)
price = models.DecimalField(validators=[isBiggerThanZero], max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre
```

I think that i need to add a new model **Cart** with a field

**saved** = models.ForeignKey(Book)

But it should be a list of books and idk how to implement it :(

**P.S.1** You should be registered if you want to save a book, so users are authorized. Skip sessions :)

**P.S.2** If there is a way to do that without additional modules, i'll be very grateful to you :)

Comment: I think it would be best to create a Cart model with user and books as foreign keys.

Comment: Could you send me an example how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use additional modules, you could create a model `Cart` with `user` and `books` as Foreign keys.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Quantity of a book that is saved in the cart. Default will be 1
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

And whenever a user visits his cart just get the data from this model and show it to the user.

The Cart Table looks like this (from above definition of `Cart` model):

```
+------+------+----------+
| User | Book | Quantity |
+------+------+----------+
|  1   |  51  |    1     |
|  2   |  95  |    1     |
|  1   |  65  |    1     |
+------+------+----------+
```

You can see that the User with `id=1` has two books (with `ids = 51` and `65`) stored in his cart and User `(id=2)` has only one book in his cart(book `id=95`).

*Add whatever fields that you may feel necessary to the above field - like price etc.,*

Comment: Could you explain please how the cart finds out what user is it and finds user's saved books?

Comment: Cart stores the instances of ```User``` and ```Book```. You can query the Cart model using the logged in user - ```request.user``` and it fetches you all the books saved by the current logged in user. As to how to add a book to the cart - it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: how? i'm beginner in Django :(

Comment: How are you adding books to your DB ? In the same way. I guess you'll be showing a 'Add to Cart' button. So when a user clicks on that button you have to add the ```user``` and the ```book``` to the Cart Table(along with any other data if necessary).

Comment: @Ihor I have updated my answer to show you clearly the structure of Cart model.

Comment: Oh, i got it! You created a general Cart, where save all users's books. Before I thought that you create the cart for everyone, thank you so much!

Comment: Please upvote and confirm my answer if you like.

Comment: i have another question. Is it effective with a big database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234453/discussion-between-ihor-and-ram).